# Singleton Object for Dynamically Imported Module in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to have a Singleton instance of a dynamically imported module in my Next.js app. However, the current implementation I have seems to initialize a new instance every time I call `getInstance`.

Here's the implementation in `gui.js`:

```
let dynamicallyImportPackage = async () => {
    let GUI;

    await import('three/examples/jsm/libs/dat.gui.module.js')

    .then(module => {
        GUI = module.GUI
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e))

    return GUI;
}

let GUI = (function () {
    let instance;

    return {
        getInstance: async () => {
            if (!instance) {
                let GUIModule = await dynamicallyImportPackage();
                instance = new GUIModule();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    };
})();

export default GUI;
```

and I call it in an ES6 class function using `GUI.getInstance().then(g => { ... })`

I would normally use React Context API or Redux for this kind of shared state but for this case, I need it to be purely in ES6 JS and not React.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cache the promise, not the instance, otherwise it will try to import the module (and instantiate another instance) again while the first is still loading and has not yet assigned the `instance` variable.

```
async function createInstance() {
    const module = await import('three/examples/jsm/libs/dat.gui.module.js')

    const { GUI } = module;

    return new GUI();
}

let instancePromise = null;

export default function getInstance() {
    if (!instancePromise) {
        instancePromise = createInstance()
        // .catch(e => {
        //    console.log(e); return ???;
        //    instancePromise = null; throw e;
        // });
    }
    return instancePromise;
}
```